# Change onmouseover command with onclick event

Tags: javascript

I have the following line in my page:

```
 <div id="fmeFriendStatus" style="width:589px;height:700px;overflow:auto" onmouseover="DelayedStatusRefresh()">
```

I want to be able to change:

```
onmouseover="DelayedStatusRefesh()"
```

command to:

```
onmouseover="DelayedStatusRefeshFriends()"
```

by clicking on a button elsewhere on the page...

Is this possible and how would you do it?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is as follows:

```
var button = document.getElementById('someButtonId');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('fmeFriendStatus').onmouseover = DelayedStatusRefeshFriends;
});
```

However, directly accessing `onclick` or other `on*` properties to listen for events is frowned upon for numerous reasons. Ideally, you would add `DelayedStatusRefesh` as an event listener using `addEventListener()` (or maybe using a JavaScript library, like jQuery), and when the button is clicked, remove that listener (`removeEventListener()`) and add the other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `onclick` handler to the second button, and its handler needs to reassign the `mouseover` handler for the `fmeFriendStatus` element.

So it should be something like this:

```
document.getElementById("buttonFromSomewhereElse").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("fmeFriendStatus").onmouseover = DelayedStatusRefeshFriends;
}
```